# find the minimum range that includes all angles in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of sorted values that represents angles (in degrees), all in the range [0,360)

My goal is to find the best range (minimum range) that fit all the angles in the list.

Some examples:

- Given the list `angles = [0,1,2,10,20,35]` the answer would be `(0,35)`.
- Given the list `angles = [10,20,340,355]`, due to the circular nature of the values, the answer would be `(340,20)`.

My current script works as follow:

```
MAX_ANGLE = 360

def get_best_range(angles):

    number_of_angles = len(angles)

    # Append the list of angles with the same angles plus 360 (max value)
    angles = angles + [angle + MAX_ANGLE for angle in angles]

    # Create a list of all possible ranges
    possible_ranges = [(angles[i], angles[i+number_of_angles - 1]) for i in range(number_of_angles)]

    # Find the best range (minimum range)
    best_range = min(possible_ranges, key = lambda ang_range: ang_range[1] - ang_range[0])

    return best_range[0], best_range[1]%MAX_ANGLE
```

Well, that is my best approach so far and it works in O(n), which is good, but just seems to me that there might be a better way to do it in python. Maybe some tool to work with circular values? I always have a bit of a hassle when working with angles or other circular values.

Comment: Do you consider 10 and 370 to be the same angle or different?

Comment: The same, I always represent the angles in the range  [0,360)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That one liner should do the trick:

```
max(zip(angles, angles[1:] + [360+angles[0]]), key = lambda x: x[1]-x[0])
```

(you can change the answer afterwards to values smaller than 360 if needed)

Comment: given that ``angles`` list is sorted

Comment: @Luchko the question starts with: "I have a list of **sorted** values"

Comment: That's is a great answer, it is just returns the range reversed, (`(35,360)` and `(340,20)` for my examples), but I just have to reverse it (can do it just by adding `[::-1]` in the one liner) and normalize in the [0,360) range. It is a much better solution than mine, thanks!

Comment: This answer would benefit from an explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def f(my_list):

     maxi = max(my_list)
     mini = min(my_list)
     if maxi - mini < 180:
        return (mini, maxi)
     else:
       return (min([x for x in my_list if x >= 180]), max([x for x in my_list if x<180]))
```